# How to access TCP flags (RST flag in specific) of the windows Socket using C++

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock

I am working on client application (in C++, using windows socket) which connects to the database server. During the data transfer between client and server, the server sends RST packet (WSAECONNRESET).

Is it possible to **read the TCP FLAGS** (I want to track the value of **RST flag** to see when it is being sent by the server) using C++ (without using raw sockets) ?? If yes, then how to access and read the RST flag (associated with the socket) value (set or unset) ?

Answer (score 1):

Sockets don't have TCP flags. TCP segments have TCP flags. Those are delivered via error codes. RST is delivered via ECONNRESET.